# Powershell ie com object html to variable

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, comobject

I am applying for a special license with the state of Texas. I am trying to have a script that will check once ever two hours to see if anything in the application status online has changed. I have already gotten to the point that it will access the website fill out my driver's license, date of birth and phone number then log into the site. My major issue is now I am trying to take the html from the ie com object and put all of it in a variable. I will post the code that I have (personal information removed). I really want the ul, li for fingerprint and background check but I will do with all of the html data instead.

```
function IEcheck() {
    $StartUrl = "https://txapps.texas.gov/txapp/txdps/ltc/"
    $ie = New-Object -ComObject internetExplorer.Application
    $ie.visible = $true
    $ie.Navigate($StartUrl)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    while ($ie.busy) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 5}
    $MainPage = $ie.Document.getElementByID('renew-trigger')
    $MainPage.click()
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    while ($ie.busy) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 5}
    $SecondPage = $ie.Document
    $DriverLicenseField = $SecondPage.getElementByID('DL')
    $DriverLicenseField.value = "00000000"
    $BirthDateField = $SecondPage.getElementByID('dob')
    $BirthDateField.value = "01/01/0001"
    $PhoneNumberField = $SecondPage.getElementByID('PHONE')
    $PhoneNumberField.value = "0000000000"
    $clickButton = $ie.Document.getElementByID("continue")
    $clickButton.click()
}

IEcheck
```

Once I am on the page if I do "view page source" I am not able to find the fields that I am looking to read but if I do inspect element I am able to find the field. Is there a way to export the html the same way it is from the inspect element section from a ie com object in powershell? Again I am just looking for a way to pull the text from Fingerprints :    Under review

[image]

Comment: [`innerText`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp)?

Comment: I agree with iRon's comment. You can locate the element first, then get the inner text of the element using `.innerText`. You can have a try.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work with this method. Might just be my own fault but I was able to get this written in python and selemium with out issues.

Comment: Have you located the elements correctly? Is there any error showing when you run the code? I found [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518596/powershell-select-html-text/47691366#47691366) which provides a solution using `.innerText`, you can also refer to it.